# puppeteer files from lib folder not exist on server side install

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, puppeteer

On my windows machine I got a lot of files in my lib folder:

- ./node_modules/puppeteer/lib

However when I install puppeteer on my ubuntu server (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) all of those files does not exist. There is only a cjs & esm folder.

I got a custom function in my script which access the lib files like this:

```js
         // extract the Page class
         const { Page } = require("puppeteer/lib/Page");

         /**
          * @name elementContains
          * @param {String} selector specific selector globally search and match
          * @param {String} text filter the elements with the specified text
          * @returns {Promise} elementHandle
          */
         Page.prototype.elementContains = function elementContains(...args) {
           return this.evaluateHandle((selector, text) => {
             // get all selectors for this specific selector
             const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
             // find element by text
             const results = elements.filter(element => element.innerText.includes(text));
             // get the last element because that's how querySelectorAll serializes the result
             return results[results.length-1];
           }, ...args);
         };



         /**
          * Replicate the .get function
          * gets an element from the executionContext
          * @param {String} selector
          * @returns {Promise}
          */
         const { JSHandle } = require("puppeteer/lib/JSHandle");
         JSHandle.prototype.get = function get(selector) {
           // get the context and evaluate inside
           return this._context.evaluateHandle(
             (element, selector) => {
               return element.querySelector(selector);
             },
             // pass the JSHandle which is itself
             this,
             selector
           );
         };
```

Everything works fine on my windows machine. However on my ubuntu server it does not work because those files does not exist. I manually uploaded all files into this folder from my windows machine however I get then:
-TypeError: page.elementContains is not a function

Can you help me please why does the lib folder doesn´t contain the needed files on linux?

Comment: How do you install puppeteer on your server.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I created my project inside of /opt/myproject and then I installed puppeteer there like default with npm i puppeteer